# Как правильно настроить заполения данных в файле settings.py

Tags: python, django

Пишу проект на Django для внутреннего пользования, вот у меня такой вопрос.
Настроил в файле `settings.py` авторизацию черед `ldap` прописал все необходимое и все работает. Хотел бы вынести эти настройки

```py
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://django.test.local'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = 'CN=bind_django, CN=USERS,DC=django, DC=test, DC=local'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = '123qwe!@#'
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
    'dc=django,dc=test,dc=local', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    'sAMAccountName=%('
    'user)s'
)
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "username": "sAMAccountName",
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
}

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
    'dc=django,dc=test, dc=local', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(objectCategory=Group)'
)
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = ActiveDirectoryGroupType(name_attr="cn")
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_superuser": 'CN=django-admins,CN=Users,DC=django, DC=test, DC=local',
    "is_staff": 'CN=django-admins,CN=Users,DC=django, DC=test, DC=local',
    "is_active": "CN=django-active,CN=Users,DC=django, DC=test, DC=local",
}
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_GROUPS = True
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 0
```

В админку, чтоб можно было ими управлять через админку, подскажите как правильно это сделать? Просто не понимаю как связать эти поля

Comment: По-моему, управлять подобными настройками через админку - очень опасная затея. Если злоумышленник случайно получит доступ к такой админке - будет весело

Comment: Сайт будет доступен с определнных IP и также он будет использоваться только как интранет, без доступа в публичную сеть @andreymal